# Inverting a "For Each" in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have some vba that finds cell contents and changes them to to #N/A

```
Dim V As Variant
For Each V In Array("A","B", "C", "F", "J")


Columns("F").Replace V, "#N/A", xlWhole, , True, , False, False
```

Is there a way I can modify this so that it inverts the ForEach and changes cells that are NOT ("A","B", "C", "F", "J")?

for example: `ForEach that is NOT V In Array("A","B", "C", "F", "J") or something like that`

I need to change everything that is NOT in the list to N/A#

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add the values you do not want to detects as keys to a dictionary,  Then use not exists to detect if the value you are testing is not a dictionary key.  Alternatively, as you items are text put then in a string (terms) and use if Instr(terms, myFind) = 0.  ) means not found.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `isInArray` function like this:

```vb
Public Sub checkValues()

Dim arrToCheck As Variant
arrToCheck = Array("A", "B", "C", "F", "J")

Dim c As Range
For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("F").Cells
    If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then
        If Not isInArray(c.Value, arrToCheck) Then
            c.Value = "#N/A"
        End If
    End If
Next

End Sub


Public Function isInArray(v As Variant, arr As Variant) As Boolean
Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    If arr(i) = v Then
        isInArray = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

### Replace (Mis)matches Using `Application.Match`

- This solution assumes that the range will have at least two cells.
- This solution is not case-sensitive (your 'Replace' is)!!!
- To use the same way to replace matches, replace the `IsError` with `IsNumeric` and switch the `0` and `rCount` lines in the `Select Case` (the functionality you achieved with `Replace` minus the case-sensitivity).
- Is it more efficient than your `Replace`? I doubt it but perform a test and let us know.
- The `Case 0` is specific here because `Match` incidentally returns the same `#N/A` error as the replacement. Otherwise, a loop minus the check is required.

```vb
Sub ReplaceMisMatches()

    Dim Arr As Variant: Arr = Array("A", "B", "C", "F", "J")

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim rg As Range:
    Set rg = ws.Range("F2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp))
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count

    Dim rIndices() As Variant: rIndices = Application.Match(rg, Arr, 0)
        
    Select Case Application.Count(rIndices)
        Case 0 ' no match; all are "#N/A"
            rg.Value = rIndices
        Case rCount ' all match; do nothing
        Case Else
            Dim Data() As Variant: Data = rg.Value
            Dim r As Long
            For r = 1 To rCount
                If IsError(rIndices(r, 1)) Then ' it's no match
                    Data(r, 1) = "#N/A"
                'Else ' it's a match; do nothing
                End If
            Next r
            rg.Value = Data
    End Select

    MsgBox "Mismatches replaced with ""#N/A"".", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

**Loop Case-Sensitive**

- This one is case-sensitive and is therefore more efficient than the same one with one of the case-insensitive suggestions in the code.
- But it is only about as fast as the `Match` solution above on 1M cells of random single characters.

```vb
Sub ReplaceMisMatchesLoop()

    Const Replacement As String = "#N/A"
    Dim Arr As Variant: Arr = Array("A", "B", "C", "F", "J")
    Dim cUpper As Long: cUpper = UBound(Arr)
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim rg As Range:
    Set rg = ws.Range("F2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp))
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count
    
    Dim Data() As Variant: Data = rg.Value

    Dim Value As Variant, r As Long, c As Long
    Dim IsMatch As Boolean, IsMisMatch As Boolean
            
    For r = 1 To rCount
        Value = Data(r, 1)
        If IsError(Value) Then
            IsMisMatch = True
        Else
            For c = 0 To cUpper
                If Arr(c) = Value Then IsMatch = True: Exit For ' case-sensitive
                'If StrComp(Arr(c), Value, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                'If LCase(Arr(c)) = LCase(Value) Then
                '    IsMatch = True: Exit For
                'End If
            Next c
            If IsMatch Then IsMatch = False Else IsMisMatch = True
        End If
        If IsMisMatch Then IsMisMatch = False: Data(r, 1) = Replacement
    Next r
    
    rg.Value = Data

    MsgBox "Mismatches replaced with ""#N/A"".", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```